# Trying to pass state between functional components but getting 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, components, state

I'm trying to pass 2 sets of state from one component to another so I can have a User's company and name listed in a Header in React. I know I'm getting the right info as I console logged both variables before setting them in my state however, when I try and render them in the Navbar I'm getting undefined.

This is my Header component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';


const Header = ({ companyName, userName }) => {
  console.log(userName);
  return (
    <header className='admin-bar'>
      <Navbar bg='white' variant='secondary' expand='lg' collapseOnSelect>
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to='/'>
            <Navbar.Brand>{companyName}</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
       <NavDropdown title={userName} id='basic-nav-dropdown'>
                <NavDropdown.Item href='#action/3.1'>Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href='#action/3.2'>Insights</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href='#action/3.3'>Settings</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Divider />
                <NavDropdown.Item href='#action/3.4'>Sign Out</NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

And my Component where I initialise the state:

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from '../aws-exports';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Upload from '../components/Upload';
import BucketList from '../components/BucketList';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const FileUploadScreen = () => {
  const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState('');
  const [userSession, setUserSession] = useState('');
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');

  const onPageRendered = async () => {
    let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    let userToken = user.getSignInUserSession().getIdToken().getJwtToken();
    setUserSession(user.getSignInUserSession());
    let base64Url = userToken.split('.')[1];
    let var1 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    let var2 = decodeURIComponent(
      atob(var1)
        .split('')
        .map(function (c) {
          return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        })
        .join('')
    );
    let company = var2.substring(
      var2.indexOf('company') + 10,
      var2.indexOf('aud') - 3
    );
    console.log(company);
    setCompanyName(company);

    let userAccountName = var2.substring(
      var2.indexOf('"name":') + 8,
      var2.indexOf('exp') - 3
    );
    setUserName(userAccountName);
    console.log(userAccountName);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onPageRendered();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
        <div className='container main p-5'>
          <h3 className='text-center pb-1 font-weight-normal bg-white'>
            Upload Files
          </h3>
          <Upload companyName={companyName} />
          <BucketList companyName={companyName} />
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FileUploadScreen;
```

And my App.js file:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import DashboardScreen from './screens/DashboardScreen';
import FileUploadScreen from './screens/FileUploadScreen';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import CompanyProfileScreen from './screens/CompanyProfileScreen';
import InsightsScreen from './screens/InsightsScreen';
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';
import Header from './components/Header';

const App = ({ companyName, userName }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header companyName={companyName} userName={userName} />
      <Sidebar />
      <main className=''>
        <Container>
          <Route path='/company' component={CompanyProfileScreen} />
          <Route path='/insights' component={InsightsScreen} />
          <Route path='/fileupload' component={FileUploadScreen} />
          <Route path='/landscape' component={DashboardScreen} />
          <Route path='/' component={WelcomeScreen} exact />
        </Container>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

As I said, I'm getting the correct names (company & username) in my console.log but once I've passed them through, nothing is rendering.

I've added my code for the BucketList component and Upload component here too for reference:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const BucketList = ({ companyName }) => {
  const [listFiles, setListFiles] = useState([]);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.REACT_APP_BUCKET_NAME,
    Delimiter: '',
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    s3.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        setListFiles(data.Contents);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  // Filtering correct file names
  let files = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
    let str = listFiles[i].Key;
    if (
      str.includes('OUTPUT') &&
      str !== `${companyName}/` &&
      str !== 'OUTPUT' &&
      str.startsWith(companyName)
    ) {
      files.push(str);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (
        files[i].endsWith(
          'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        )
      ) {
        files[i] = files[i].replace(
          '.vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
          '.xlsx'
        );
      } else if (files[i].endsWith('.vnd.ms-excel')) {
        files[i] = files[i].replace('.vnd.ms-excel', '.csv');
      }
    }
  }

  // Adding dynamic class to card for scroll
  useEffect(() => {
    files.length > 3 && setIsVisible(true);
  }, [files.length]);

  return (
    <div className={`card my-4 ${isVisible ? 'test' : ''}`}>
      <div className='card-header'>{companyName} Current Files</div>
      <ListGroup className='list-group'>
        {files &&
          files.map((name, index) => (
            <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
              {name.split('/').slice(2)}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          ))}
      </ListGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BucketList;
```

```
import React, { useRef, useState, Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Message from './Message';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const Upload = ({ companyName }) => {
  const bucketName = process.env.REACT_APP_BUCKET_NAME;

  const fileInput = useRef();

  const [filename, setFilename] = useState('Choose File');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [fileInfos, setFileInfos] = useState([]);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [showProgressBar, setShowProgressBar] = useState(false);
  const [isScroll, setIsScroll] = useState(false);

  const selectFile = (e) => {
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
  };

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newArr = fileInput.current.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
      handleUpload(newArr[i]);
    }
  };

  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY,
  });

  const myBucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
      Bucket: `${bucketName}/${companyName}`,
    },
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
  });

  const handleUpload = (file) => {
    const params = {
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Key: file.name,
      ContentType: file.type,
      Body: file,
    };

    let newFileName = file.name;

    myBucket
      .putObject(params)
      .on('httpUploadProgress', (evt) => {
        setProgress(Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100));
        setFileInfos([newFileName, ...fileInfos]);
        setMessage('File uploaded');
      })
      .send((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          setShowProgressBar(false);
          setMessage('Could not upload file');
        }
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fileInfos.length >= 2 && setIsScroll(true);
  }, [fileInfos.length]);

  if (progress === 100) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setProgress(0);
      setShowProgressBar(false);
      setMessage('');
    }, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form className='bg-white my-4' onSubmit={handleClick}>
        {message ? <Message msg={message} /> : null}
        <div className='custom-file mb-2'>
          <input
            type='file'
            onChange={selectFile}
            multiple
            ref={fileInput}
            id='customFile'
            className='custom-file-input'
          />

          <label className='custom-file-label' htmlFor='customFile'>
            {filename}
          </label>
        </div>
        {showProgressBar ? <ProgressBar percentage={progress} /> : null}

        <input
          type='submit'
          value='Upload'
          className='btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3'
          disabled={filename === 'Choose File'}
          onClick={() => setShowProgressBar(true)}
        />

        <br />

        <div className={`card ${isScroll ? 'test' : ''}`}>
          <div className='card-header'>Recently Added</div>
          <ListGroup className='list-group'>
            {fileInfos &&
              fileInfos.map((file, index) => (
                <ListGroup.Item key={index}>{file}</ListGroup.Item>
              ))}
          </ListGroup>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Upload;
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you have to define your async function `onPageRendered` into the useEffect hook.

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) could you share the code for the `BucketList` and `Upload` components? (2) could you share any error you might see in console?

Comment: I couldn't see you passing values from FileUploadScreen to Header component to display your data

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've added my code BucketList and Upload too @secan - I'm not getting any errors in the console, but if i console.log(userName) in the Header component I get back 'undefined' however, console.logging userName in the FileUploadScreen component gives me the correct info

Comment: @KeerthiVijay thanks for your reply, I'm still learning quite alot about React, is that where I am going wrong by the looks of it? I thought as I am destructuring them in the Header component that they are now passed in correctly?

Comment: You set your username and company name only in the FileUploadScreen component state alone, it will not be available for other components unless you pass. As it being an auth username, you can store in localStorage to maintain and access across all your component without losing it even reload.

Comment: @Asher you `Header` component is loaded by the `App` component and the `App` component does not know anything about `companyName`. In a React app, state and props can be passed "downward" (from the parent to the children) but not "upward". If you want `companyName` to be available for `Header` you can make `companyName` part of the `App` state (as `App` is `Header`'s parent) or you can use some centralized state management library like, for example [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: I see, I understand that now - thanks alot to both of you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following dependencies to your useEffect hook, so it updates when you get the company name and user name :

```
useEffect(() => {
    onPageRendered();
  }, [companyName, userName]);
```

Comment: Thanks alot however I'm still having the same issue where both must be undefined as nothing is rendering in the UI

Comment: Maybe it is because you don't give the companyName and the userName from the FileUploadScreen  to the Header component

Comment: I don't understand the component structure. Header is rendered by App, but who render App ? and where is FileUploadScreen rendered ?

Comment: In Header, I thought I was passing companyName and userName in like so:

'const Header = ({ companyName, userName }) => {'

FileUploadScreen is rendered in App, I believe I was passing both sets of state into the Header component as props like I've pasted above

Comment: you have the variable companyName and userName in the FileUploadScreen. But you never give them to the Header component.

Comment: Your FileUploadComponent is not rendered in the App component also

Comment: I see, thanks. What is the best way for me to give them to the Header component?

I thought I was rendering FileUploadScreen in the App like so:

`<Route path='/fileupload' component={FileUploadScreen} />`

Comment: You are indeed doing it, but frome where are you getting the App props ?

Comment: I thought I was getting them from passing them into App using destructuring like so: 

`const App = ({ companyName, userName }) => {`

?

Comment: Yes but nobody give them to the App, or it is ?

Comment: Then you have to review your structure, and get the state in the right component, and give it to the others. Moreover, I don't think that with the route like you do you are actually passing props: https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-components/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and find an alternative route!

Answer (score 1):

**Why This Happnes**

1. The Setter method in the useState hook is a Async function.
2. The function You are calling in side the useEffect Hook is also a Async Function
3. Now as you have set no dependencies in the useEffect Hook, at the initialization the programme loads, sends the async function in the wepApi(event loop).
4. As the initial value of the sate is an empty string & the programme runs initially without caring about the Async function, You are left with empty values in the jsx.

**How to solve it**

1. Just pass the dependencies in the useEffect dependency array

   useEffect(() => {
   onPageRendered();
   }, [companyName, userName]);
2. Additionally you can add conditional rendering in the jsx to check if the value exist.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I did add both as dependencies just now however, I'm still having the same issue where both must be undefined still as nothing is rendering in the UI